# No data output in Zapier when running a Python Code block and inputting a list

Tags: python-3.x, zapier

I am taking what I believe is a list from a previous step in Zapier and trying to then compare that list to a dictionary (within the code) to return a value or group of values as a new list.  I have tested this out successfully on my desktop, but it does not result in the same output in Zapier.

My previous step takes a comma separated list and uses the `Utlities` formatter to return a list.  My error could be that I am assuming this is a list.

[image]
I assume this is a list and use it as the input for the `Run Python` step.

[image]

When I test and review this, the outcome has no errors, but no data either.  Any insight would be awesome as to how I make sure I understand the incoming data.

**Zapier Test**

```
list = []
for arg in input.values():
    sharefile={
    'Explore! Archaeology': 'https://hectv.sharefile.com/xxxx',
    'Explore! Life as a Dog': 'https://hectv.sharefile.com/xxxx',
    'Explore! Economics': 'https://hectv.sharefile.com/xxxx',
    'The big chicken': 'https://hectv.sharefile.com/xxxx'
    }
    for index, (key, value) in enumerate(sharefile.items()):
        if arg == key:
            print(f'{arg} was matched')
            list.append(value)
return(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the crew at Zapier, they explained that the input will always be text.  Each input row is one dictionary entry.

Therefore, to access my first and only row of data, I had to use:

`items = input_data['input']`

This returns a string of data.

I hope that helps anyone with the issue.